# make errors due to DXLIB=1 option

Tags: gcc, makefile

I need to install a rather big code written in Fortran and C on a CentOS box. The installation instructions state that one should start running the configure command from autoconf followed by make. A lot of compilation takes place of C-routines into object files. All of a sudden, towards the end of the compilation a series of errors is issued: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token. The command generating the errors is:

```
gcc  -DCEM=1 -DHISTP=1 -DSPABI=1 -DDFACT=1 -DXS64=1 -DPLOT=1 -DMCPLOT=1 -DGKSSIM=1 -DXLIB=1 -DCHEAP=1  -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local\" -DLIBPREFIX=\"/usr/local/lib\"  -I../../../../AAAA/src/AAAA/AAAAc/../../include ../../../../AAAA/src/AAAA/AAAAc/AAAAc.c -c -o AAAAc.o
```

When I remove the option -DXLIB=1 the same routine compiles perfectly.
I tried finding out from man make how this issue could be resolved but do not find a hook. Could someone provide me with a hint? 
Thanks in advance,
Stefan

Comment: It has nothing to do with make. You need a C programmer to debug why
your C preprocessor defines, when they include `-DXLIB=1`, result
in this C syntax error. You will not get an answer here unless you
can provide an [mcve] for C programmers to study.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but compiling without the DXLIB option does not give errors, so I conclude from this that it is not really a code of syntax issue. What is this -DXLIB=1 really doing and how was it inserted in the compiler command line?

Comment: Hi. `-DXLIB=1` (option `-D`, argument `XLIB=1`) passes a preprocessor macro `XLIB` defined as `1` to the
C compiler. Macros can control to an abrtitrary extent what sequence of
source characters is fed to the compiler, hence whether it is syntactically
valid sequence or not. `expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token.` *is*
a GCC C syntax error diagnostic, a commonplace one. It is triggered here by the effect of `-DXLIB=1`
on the source code the compiler is seeing. How? - That needs an MVCE.